# NullPointerException when using @PreAuthorize in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, lombok

I am working on a Spring Boot project where I have implemented Spring Security to manage JWT authentication. I have a ProductController with a **ProductService** autowired in it. When I add the **@PreAuthorize** annotation to one of my controller methods, I encounter a **NullPointerException** related to the productService field.

Note: I encountered the issue after adding Spring Security

Here is my controller code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CLIENT')")
    private Page<ProductDTO> getProducts(
            @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "10") int size) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        return productService.findAll(pageable);
    }
    // ... 
}
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.arinashoe.catalogservice.service.ProductService.findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)" because "this.productService" is null
```

However, when I remove the @PreAuthorize annotation, the method works without any issues.

I am using Spring Boot 3.1.2, and I followed this tutorial for implementing JWT authentication: [https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/].

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

I have also tried the following method with @PreAuthorize, and it works fine:

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CLIENT')")
private String testMethod(Authentication authentication) {
    if (authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String userId = userDetails.getUsername(); // Assuming username represents the userId
        return "User ID: " + userId;
    }
    return "User ID not available";
}
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I've found a lead https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8879

Comment: to fix the problem we have to change the access modifier to `public`.

Comment: when we use `@Preauthorize`or any similar annotation, Spring Security creates proxy around the bean `ProductController` to intercept method calls and apply security checks. The proxying mechanism relies on java interfaces or public methods to create the proxy

Comment: A `private` method cannot be proxied hence the actual call of the method is done on the proxy, instead of passing in along to the proxied object. Make the method `public` to allow for proper proxying.

Answer (score -3):

```
@Service <-- here
public Class ProductService {
   .....
}
```

**You can check to see if @Service has been defined yet.**

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null`. The application would simply fail to start, as that isn't the case it isn't the problem of a missing dependency.